# Adding a friendly Url in Dynamic Views of Angular8 to use SEO

Tags: angular, typescript, seo, url-routing, angular8

i'm using Angular routing to switch between views.

My version of Angular is `"@angular/core": "~8.0.0"`

This is how it's done today:

```
www.mywebsite.com.br
```

When i chose some view, i load a data from the server to show the info, and the URL look's like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com.br/course/1
```

But, to use SEO in my website i need to show the tittle of the course in the URL, like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com.br/how-to-use-a-computer
```

And when i navigate inside this course i need to create the path, like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com.br/how-to-use-a-computer/my-first-class
```

This, my routes:

```
const routes = [

  {path: 'manufacturer/:id_ manufacturer', component: ManufacturerComponent},

  {path: 'course/:id_course', component: CourseComponent},

  {path: 'category/:id_ category', component: CategoryComponent},

  {path: 'course/:id_course/class/:id_ class', component: ClassComponent},
];
```

There is anyway to change the URL?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check your module imports, the `#` can be disabled by providing `{ useHash: false }` as the second argument of the `RouterModule.forRoot`:

```
imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })  // set it as false to disable the #
]
```

This is where you probably overridden your `LocationStrategy`, which defaults to `PathLocationStrategy` (the one without a hash). The other option is `HashLocationStrategy`, which behaves as you described it (with a `#`). You can read more about `LocationStrategy` in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles).

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, with your tip i removed the `#`, but how can i change the rest of the URL another string, in my case, the title of the course

Comment: OP asked about making seo friendly url's :/, not about removing/adding # to url. @LeonelTassoGuimaraes why did u accept wrong answer ?